# Change value depends on the position of an array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

It seems I have a problem regarding arrays that would change the value of first array depending on the value and position of the second array. It would seem to hard to explain in words, I'll give an example to make this a little bit more of understanding.

I have this first array

```
Array
(
    [0] => one
    [1] => two
    [2] => three
    [3] => four
    [4] => five
)
```

and this is my second array

```
Array
(
    [0] => 
    [1] => cat
    [2] => 
    [3] => dog
    [4] => 
)
```

and my desired result should be like this

```
Array
(
    [0] => one
    [1] => cat
    [2] => three
    [3] => dog
    [4] => five
)
```

so if I changed my second array into this

```
Array
(
    [0] => 
    [1] =>
    [2] => 
    [3] => dog
    [4] => cat
)
```

The result would be like this

```
Array
(
    [0] => one
    [1] => two
    [2] => three
    [3] => dog
    [4] => cat
)
```

So meaning, the second array would be like the replacement of the first array.

Well I used **array_diff** to get the difference of the two arrays and that's where I'm stuck.

Any help would be appreciated though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be a better way but you could do something like:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($array1); $i++) {
    if ($array2[$i] == null || $array2[$i] == "") {
        $newArray[$i] = $array1[$i];
    }
    else {
        $newArray[$i] = $array2[$i];
    }
}
```

`$newArray` will contain all values from `$array1` unless a non-null or empty value exists in `$array2` (based on the array index), in which case it will overwrite the value that was in `$array1`.

Comment: The answer that I was looking for! Fantastic! Thanks a lot. :)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this link about

```
array_merge
```

could be usefull

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php

Comment: Array merge will combine two arrays regardless of the indexes.  Good info, but not really what he's asking for.

Comment: @Adam Plocher. Ok, I agree.

Answer (score 1):

I think this should work:

```
foreach($second_array as $k => $v)
{
    if($v != "")
    {
        $first_array[$k] = $v;
    }
}
```

demo [here](http://codepad.org/IBzimhDj)

Answer (score 1):

the easiest thing to do would be to loop through your second array and assign it's value to the first based on the key...

```
$arr1=array ("one","two","three","four","five");
$arr2=array( 2=>"cat",4="dog");

foreach ($arr2 as $key=>$value){
 if (!empty($value)){
    $arr1[$key]=$value;
  }
}
```

Comment: Based on his post, it would appear that he has empty values in his second array with matching keys.  If that's true, then he's just going to overwrite his values in array1.

Comment: yep I caught that right after I posted it. added a condition to my statement